# MOM estimator same as MLE estimator for normal distribution

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Q: Let X1,...,Xn be IID N(μ, σ²) r.v. Is the MOM estimators for σ² and μ same as the MLE estimators?

For Uniform distribution, i remembered that the MOM and MLE estimators corresponds and are the same, but is it the same for normal distribution?

Comment: What are the parameters of interest?

Comment: For $\mu$, both the MOM estimator and MLE turn out to be the sample mean. You can try deriving these estimators and see for yourself..

Comment: Perhaps a less tidy question than you intended: There are several distinct estimation problems for UNIF: $\mathsf{Unif}(0,\theta),\,$ $\mathsf{Unif}(\mu-,\mu+\theta),\,$ etc. In the first of these, MOM and MLE for $\theta$ are _not_  the same. The second is messy.//
Not all MLE.s are unbiased, MOM's are unbiased if only linear arithmetic is used in deriving them. Are MOM and MLE the "same" if they differ only by an unbiassing constant?